# Separate year from month in date format

Tags: r

Suppose I have this list containing year and month:

```
l <- c(200101, 200102 ,200103, 200104)
```

I want to separate them so that I can have then into `2` separate lists.
Here is what I did with no luck:

```
as.Date(l,"%Y%m",format = "%Y")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would work :

```
year_list<-as.numeric(substr(as.numeric(l),1,4))
month_list<-as.numeric(substr(as.numeric(l),5,6))
```

Example 1:

```
> l <- c(200101, 200102 ,200103, 200104)
> l
[1] 200101 200102 200103 200104

> year_list<-as.numeric(substr(as.numeric(l),1,4))
> year_list
[1] 2001 2001 2001 2001

> month_list<-as.numeric(substr(as.numeric(l),5,6))
> month_list
[1] 1 2 3 4
```

Example 2:

```
> l <- c(200701, 200802 ,200903, 201604)
> year_list<-as.numeric(substr(as.numeric(l),1,4))
> year_list
[1] 2007 2008 2009 2016
> month_list<-as.numeric(substr(as.numeric(l),5,6))
> month_list
[1] 1 2 3 4
```

Answer (score 4):

You could do:

```
rbind(floor(l/100), l%%100)

#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,] 2001 2001 2001 2001
#[2,]    1    2    3    4
```

Answer (score 3):

`tidyr::separate` can take an integer position to split on, but it only takes data.frames. That's not all bad here, though, as it's a nice output format anyway:

```
library(tidyr)

data.frame(l = c(200101, 200102 ,200103, 200104)) %>% 
    separate(l, into = c('year', 'month'), sep = 4)
##   year month
## 1 2001    01
## 2 2001    02
## 3 2001    03
## 4 2001    04
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `strsplit` from `base R`

```
 do.call(rbind, lapply(strsplit(as.character(l), 
                  '(?<=.{4})', perl=TRUE), as.numeric))
```

---

Or another `base R` option by creating a delimiter between the characters and use `read.csv`

```
read.csv(text=sub("(.{4})(.{2})", "\\1,\\2", l), header=FALSE, 
           col.names= c("Year", "Month"))
#   Year Month
#1 2001     1
#2 2001     2
#3 2001     3
#4 2001     4
```